# error using "nltk.word_tokenize()" function

Tags: python, twitter, nlp, nltk, tokenize

I'm trying to tokenize twitter text.
When I apply the function nltk.word_tokenize() each single twitter text, it works perfectly even for some very ugly one such as

> '\xd8\xb3\xd8\xa3\xd9\x87\xd9\x8e\xd9\x85\xd9\x90\xd8\xb3\xd9\x8f',
>   '\xd9\x82\xd9\x90\xd8\xb5\xd9\x8e\xd9\x91\xd8\xa9\xd9\x8b',
>   '\xd8\xad\xd8\xaa\xd9\x89'

but when I loop through all the twitter in a file

```
tokens = []
for i in range(0,5047591):
    s = ','.join(l_of_l[i])
    tokens += nltk.word_tokenize(s)
```

it returns errors such as:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 2:     ordinal not in range(128)File
>   "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nltk/tokenize/punkt.py", line 1304,
>   in _realign_boundaries
>       for sl1, sl2 in _pair_iter(slices):

and many more

any suggestion about how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you're getting is not from the code you included, it's from the code that include `open()` command. The script is opening the file fine, but when you're accessing your data, it's give you that TraceBack

```
import codecs
...
with codecs.open('file.csv','r',encoding='utf8') as f:
    text = f.read()
```

Comment: Thanks! I did f.readline() instead but I got this error "UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte", and I'm not quite sure what to do with it

Comment: There are two possible solutions for that second error. 1) change that line to `with codecs.open('file.csv', 'r',encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as f:` but risk losing *some* characters. 2) Determine what type of encoding you're dealing with then do `decode('######').encode('utf-8')`. It's common to use `.decode('cp1252')` but please be aware that's not guaranteed to be the correct one.

Comment: yeah you are right, when I use errors = 'ignore', the list I constructed from the file became "index out of range"

Comment: but the decode(). statement is not resolved, I wonder some setting problem about my pycharm maybe, because occasionally I can't even install some modules

Comment: This might help with pycharm actually, now that you mentioned it. Go to File>Settings>Editor>File Encoding then change "IDE encoding", "Project encoding", and (at the bottom) "Default encondig for properties files" to 'UTF-8'. Take away the `errors='ignore'` and run the script again. I haven't tested it, but you might be able to remove codecs as well tho. Again, the problem with that it's that it's specific (benefit) to pycharm.

Comment: Thanks I did, but now my error code looks like this "UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte"